# How to add a (*) into the align environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

How can I add a (*) to the align environment with some regular equation in the center?

It's so I can type afterwards, "By (*), ..."

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You're probably interested in `\tag{*}\label{eq:label}` and then use `\eqref{eq:label}` elsewhere in your document.

Comment: Do you really want a (*) or an equation number?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it is not rare to use some symbols for some very important equation.

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, I do that in hand-written equations as well -- depends on the topics, I believe...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In my field it's uncommon to number equations or, more generally, displayed formulas; those which are referred to elsewhere in the paper are often marked up by symbols such as (*).

Comment: @egreg: In Astrophysics, important equations are numbered, but it's a matter of taste and sometimes a convention of the author(s)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) - loaded if you're using an `align`-like environment - provides `\tag{<stuff>}` where you can place whatever you like in the "equation number". Perhaps the following is what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= x^3 - 1 \tag{$\star$}\label{eq:starred}
\end{align}
It should be clear from~\eqref{eq:starred} what you're after.

\end{document}
```

You can also use this with another `align`-like environment, or even `equation`.